# WPF Binding - avoiding levels of indirection

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm populating a context menu dynamically, using a class like this to represent each item:-

```
public class ContextMenuItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Header {get;set;}
    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
    public ICommand Command {get;set;}
    ..etc..
}
```

*Note the properties implement the standard INotifyPropertyChanged stuff, which I've left out here to save space.*

I won't include the XAML - the above properties are simply bound to their `MenuItem` counterparts.

Here's my problem. I would like a menu item's `IsChecked` state to "track" the value of another model's boolean property. E.g:-

```
var menuItem = new ContextMenuItem
    {
       Caption = "Online?", 
       IsChecked = user.IsOnline
    };
```

This clearly won't work properly - although the menu item's checked state *will* initially reflect the user's online state, the checked state won't change as `user.IsOnline` changes.

One approach is to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of the `user` object, and change `IsChecked` whenever `IsOnline` changes, but this feels a bit convoluted. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make `IsChecked` a [dependancy property](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property) and your class a DependencyObject you could bind them together like so

```
 public class ContextMenuItem : DependencyObject
 {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = 
          DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(ContextMenuItem ));


    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty) as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }
    }
 }

 var binding = new Binding("IsOnline");
 binding.Source = user;
 binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(menuItem,ContextMenuItem.IsCheckedProperty,binding);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your user object also implement INotifyPropertyChanged you can expose User in your VM and bind directly to it.

```
 <... IsCheck="{Binding User.IsOnline}" ... >
```

but your approach to subscribe to user PropertyChanged work well too :) there are some helper classes around wich reduce the boiler code